# Line-breaking a long numerator in a fraction expression

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I have a problem with splitting this long equation . i tried `aligned` env and `split` of `amsmath` package but nothing worked !!  Any help .

```
 $ Sym_{vertical} =  \frac { \mid X^{'}_{UL} - X^{'}_{UR}\mid 
+ \mid X^{'}_{LL} - X^{'}_{LR}\mid 
+ \mid Y^{'}_{UL} - Y^{'}_{UR}\mid             \\  
+\mid Y^{'}_{LL} - Y^{'}_{LR} \mid 
+ \mid H^{'}_{UL} - X^{'}_{UR} \mid 
+ \mid H^{'}_{LL} - H^{'}_{LR} \mid  \\
+\mid B^{'}_{UL} - B^{'}_{UR} \mid 
+ \mid B^{'}_{LL} - B^{'}_{LR} \mid 
+ \mid \Theta^{'}_{UL} - \Theta^{'}_{UR} \mid  \\
+ \mid \Theta^{'}_{LL} - \Theta^{'}_{LR} \mid 
+ \mid R^{'}_{UL} - R^{'}_{UR} \mid 
+ \mid R^{'}_{LL} - R^{'}_{LR} \mid}
{12}$
```

i want it to look this way :[image]

Comment: `12 SYM_{\mathrm{horizontal}} = ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made the numerator a left-aligned `\Longstack` (in math mode).  I also had to change a few `\\+` to `+\\` and made the left side of the equation in `\mathrm`.

Mico was right to point out that `\mid`s should be replaced with `\lvert`, `\rvert` pairs, and `^{'}` is redundant and should be just employed as `'`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\mathrm{Sym}_\mathrm{vertical} =  \frac 
{ \Longstack[l]{\lvert X'_{UL} - X'_{UR}\rvert 
+ \lvert X'_{LL} - X'_{LR}\rvert 
+ \lvert Y'_{UL} - Y'_{UR}\rvert             +\\  
\lvert Y'_{LL} - Y'_{LR} \rvert 
+ \lvert H'_{UL} - X'_{UR} \rvert 
+ \lvert H'_{LL} - H'_{LR} \rvert  +\\
\lvert B'_{UL} - B'_{UR} \rvert 
+ \lvert B'_{LL} - B'_{LR} \rvert 
+ \lvert \Theta'_{UL} - \Theta'_{UR} \rvert  +\\
 \lvert \Theta'_{LL} - \Theta'_{LR} \rvert 
+ \lvert R'_{UL} - R'_{UR} \rvert 
+ \lvert R'_{LL} - R'_{LR} \rvert}}
{12}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If term alignment is useful, the a TABstack can be used, instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\mathrm{Sym}_\mathrm{vertical} =  \frac 
{ \tabbedLongstack[l]{\lvert X'_{UL} - X'_{UR}\rvert 
&+ \lvert X'_{LL} - X'_{LR}\rvert 
&+ \lvert Y'_{UL} - Y'_{UR}\rvert            & +\\  
\lvert Y'_{LL} - Y'_{LR} \rvert 
&+ \lvert H'_{UL} - X'_{UR} \rvert 
&+ \lvert H'_{LL} - H'_{LR} \rvert  &+\\
\lvert B'_{UL} - B'_{UR} \rvert 
&+ \lvert B'_{LL} - B'_{LR} \rvert 
&+ \lvert \Theta'_{UL} - \Theta'_{UR} \rvert  &+\\
 \lvert \Theta'_{LL} - \Theta'_{LR} \rvert 
&+ \lvert R'_{UL} - R'_{UR} \rvert 
&+ \lvert R'_{LL} - R'_{LR} \rvert&}}
{12}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Use a fraction in front of the expression:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathit{Sym}_{\mathrm{vertical}} =
\tfrac{1}{12}(\,
  \begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
  & \abs{ X'_{UL} - X'_{UR} } &&+ \abs{ X'_{LL} - X'_{LR} } &&+ {}\\
  & \abs{ Y'_{UL} - Y'_{UR} } &&+ \abs{ Y'_{LL} - Y'_{LR} } &&+ {}\\
  & \abs{ H'_{UL} - X'_{UR} } &&+ \abs{ H'_{LL} - H'_{LR} } &&+ {}\\
  & \abs{ B'_{UL} - B'_{UR} } &&+ \abs{ B'_{LL} - B'_{LR} } &&+ {}\\
  & \abs{ \Theta'_{UL} - \Theta'_{UR}  } &&+ \abs{ \Theta'_{LL} - \Theta'_{LR} } &&+ {}\\
  & \abs{ R'_{UL} - R'_{UR} } &&+ \abs{ R'_{LL} - R'_{LR} }\,)
\end{alignedat}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative with the plus signs at the left side.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split}
\mathit{Sym}_{\mathrm{vertical}} = 
\tfrac{1}{12}(\,
  &  \abs{ X'_{UL} - X'_{UR} } + \abs{ X'_{LL} - X'_{LR} } \\
  &+ \abs{ Y'_{UL} - Y'_{UR} } + \abs{ Y'_{LL} - Y'_{LR} } \\
  &+ \abs{ H'_{UL} - X'_{UR} } + \abs{ H'_{LL} - H'_{LR} } \\
  &+ \abs{ B'_{UL} - B'_{UR} } + \abs{ B'_{LL} - B'_{LR} } \\
  &+ \abs{ \Theta'_{UL} - \Theta'_{UR}  } + \abs{ \Theta'_{LL} - \Theta'_{LR} } \\
  &+ \abs{ R'_{UL} - R'_{UR} } + \abs{ R'_{LL} - R'_{LR} }\,)
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: other than it's how the op showed it, why would you not place the plus signs at the beginning of the continuation lines?

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's a possible choice, I'll add it: your wish is my command, as you know.

Answer (score 10):

The `mathtools` package provides the macros `\splitfrac` and `\splitdfrac` for just your use case. You may prefer the solution with either four or three split lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}
\[ \textit{Sym}_{\mathrm{vertical}} =  
\frac {% 
\splitdfrac{\abs{X'_{UL} - X'_{UR}}
+ \abs{X'_{LL} - X'_{LR}}
+ \abs{Y'_{UL} - Y'_{UR}}}{%  
\splitdfrac{{}+ \abs{Y'_{LL} - Y'_{LR}}
+ \abs{H'_{UL} - X'_{UR}}
+ \abs{H'_{LL} - H'_{LR}}}{%
\splitdfrac{{}+ \abs{B'_{UL} - B'_{UR}}
+ \abs{B'_{LL} - B'_{LR}}
+ \abs{\Theta'_{UL} - \Theta'_{UR}}}{%
+ \abs{\Theta'_{LL} - \Theta'_{LR}}
+ \abs{R'_{UL} - R'_{UR}}
+ \abs{R'_{LL} - R'_{LR}} }}} }
{12}
\] 

\begin{multline*}
\textit{Sym}_{\mathrm{vertical}} =  \\
\frac {% 
\splitdfrac{
  \abs{X'_{UL} - X'_{UR}}+ \abs{X'_{LL} - X'_{LR}}
+ \abs{Y'_{UL} - Y'_{UR}}+ \abs{Y'_{LL} - Y'_{LR}}}{%  
\splitdfrac{{}
+ \abs{H'_{UL} - X'_{UR}}+ \abs{H'_{LL} - H'_{LR}}
+ \abs{B'_{UL} - B'_{UR}}+ \abs{B'_{LL} - B'_{LR}}}{%  
+ \abs{\Theta'_{UL} - \Theta'_{UR}} + \abs{\Theta'_{LL} - \Theta'_{LR}}
+ \abs{R'_{UL} - R'_{UR}} + \abs{R'_{LL} - R'_{LR}} }}}
{12}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```